# sed - Print lines matched by a pattern range if one line matches a condition

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a multi line log entry format that I need to process.

The log looks something like this:

```
--START--
Device=B
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
--START--
Device=B
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
--START--
Device=B
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
--START--
Device=C
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
```

I want to print everything between `--START--` and `--END--` if a particular pattern is matched.

e.g:

Print all entries where `Device=A`

```
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
```

All I've been able to do so far is write:

```
sed -e -n '/--START--/,/--END--/p' < input
```

Which effectively prints the input but I think I need to add `{}` to filter with `N` and then print if that condition matches.

I also think I'm completely lost.

Any idea on how to print multiple lines if a single line matches a condition?

Comment: This is great guys. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$ sed -n '/--START--/{:a;N;/--END--/!ba; /Device=A/p}' file
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
```

(The above was tested on GNU sed.  It would have to be massaged to run on BSD/OSX.)

How it works:

- `/--START--/{...}`

  Every time we reach a line that contains `--START--`, run the commands inside the braces `{...}`.
- `:a`

  Define a label `a`.
- `N`

  Read the next line and add it to the pattern space.
- `/--END--/!ba`

  Unless the pattern space now contains `--END--`, jump back to label `a`.
- `/Device=A/p`

  If we get here, that means that the patterns space starts with `--START--` and ends with `--END--`.  If, in addition, the pattern space contains `Device=A`, then print (`p`) it.

Comment: Finally tried these guys. This implementation both produces the right results and is the most concise.

Comment: You, sir, just single-handedly taught me how to think in `sed`:  labels in C. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, worked great for me. I used the trick to substitue text within a certain xml-element.
sed -i -E '/<Element.*/{:a;N;/<\/Element>/!ba;s/Pattern/Replacement/}' file

Answer (score 7):

Other `sed` variant with hold space use

```
sed 'H              #add line to hold space
     /--START--/h   #put START into hold space (substitute holded in)
     /--END--/!d    #clean pattern space (start next line) if not END
     x              #put hold space into pattern space
     /Device=A/!d   #clean pattern space if it have not "Device=A"
    ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ -e:1 -e'$!N;/--END--/{
  /Device=A/!d
  b
}' -eb1 <file
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
Lorem=Ipsum
--END--
--START--
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf
--END--
```

This read all line between `--START--` and `--END--` into pattern space. If matched `--END--`, we check if pattern space didn't contain `Device=A`, delete it, else `sed` print pattern space then start next cycle.

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  /--START--/ {
    getline d
    if (d ~ /Device=A/) {
      p = 1
      printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, d
      next
     }
  }
  p
  /--END--/ { p = 0 }
' <file
```

Comment: With GNU awk you can just parse match and print each group as a record: `gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="--END--\n"} /Device=A/'`. To match only on the first line after `--START--` also set `FS="\n"` and test `$2=="Device=A"` .

Answer (score 0):

There are already several other good answers here which demonstrate how to test for your string between *`--START--`* and *`--END--`* blocks, but, given your sample input, it could be that you don't really need to worry about *`--START--`* at all.

```
sed -n '$!N;/^Device=A\n/,/\n--END--/P;D'
```

...would print everything from *`Device=A`* through to the last `\n`ewline occurring just before the next occurring *`--END--`* in each block. It doesn't bother to worry about *`--START--`* because it doesn't appear there's ever any need to check for it.

So for a block like:

```
--START--
Device=A
...stuff...
--END--
```

...the output would be...

```
Device=A
...stuff...
```

...but for a block like...

```
--START--
Device=B
Device=A
...stuff...
--END--
```

...it would output the same.

It works by appending the `N`ext input line to every line which is `!` not the `$` last, and so pattern space looks like:

```
^line1\nline2$
```

For every pattern space which occurs between the sequences *`^Device=A\n`* and *`\n--END--`* the first of the two lines currently in pattern is `P`rinted and afterward `D`eleted before starting the next cycle with what remains. And so the next pattern space looks like...

```
^line2\nline3$
```