# How to use sed to extract from xml after doing a pattern match in one of the tags inside?

Tags: sed, xml

```
<Response 
            <MessageID>ID:c3e2</MessageID>
             <Year>2018</Year>
            <ClntID>ABC</ClntID>
            <ParticipantID>12346789</ParticipantID>
            <ProductType>RU</ProductType>
           <Date>19010101<tDate>
          </Response>
```

In the above response, i want to copy the full response,only if the value of participantID is 12346789. How can i achieve this with sed or grep command?

Comment: @Shri, I've rolled back your question to the one that steve answered. It's best if you can ask a Good Question initially, so that you get Good, applicable answers. Given the large change, it's probably better that you ask a new question with the new requirements and accept one of the existing answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically asked for `sed`, here goes.

```
$ sed -n '/^<Response/{:a;N;/<\/Response>/!ba;/<ParticipantID>12346789/p}' inp
<Response
            <MessageID>ID:c3e2</MessageID>
             <Year>2018</Year>
            <ClntID>ABC</ClntID>
            <ParticipantID>12346789</ParticipantID>
            <ProductType>RU</ProductType>
           <Date>19010101<tDate>
          </Response>
$
```

Similar code to [sed - Print lines matched by a pattern range if one line matches a condition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228699/sed-print-lines-matched-by-a-pattern-range-if-one-line-matches-a-condition) from @John1024

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the XML is well formed and without errors (the XML in the question has errors), and that `Response` is the root node of the document, using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/Response[ParticipantID="12346789"]' -nl file.xml
<Response>
            <MessageID>ID:c3e2</MessageID>
             <Year>2018</Year>
            <ClntID>ABC</ClntID>
            <ParticipantID>12346789</ParticipantID>
            <ProductType>RU</ProductType>
           <Date>19010101</Date>
          </Response>
```

This will give you back a copy of the document if the `/Response/ParticipantID` node has a value of `12346789`.

The XPATH query `/Response[ParticipantID="12346789"]` will select the `Response` node, but only if its `ParticipantID` has the specified value. The `-c` flag to `xmlstarlet` asks for a copy (as opposed to `-v` which would return the values).

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention this is present inside a txt file and i need to copy the extracted response to another txt file ..is that possible ?

Comment: @Shri Of course it's _possible_. Is it possible that you may show how it's embedded in the rest of the document? (edit your question to add more information)

Comment: i have changed the question..sorry for the confusion.. i am new to this