# Printing sectioned parts in terminal

Tags: bash

I have some files that have the following construct in them.  I want to print the whole sections present.  The input would be other a title or keywords.

```
## DN [TITLE] KEYWORD,KEYWORD
## text line
## another text line
## DN [TITLE] ends here
```

Consider this file

```
some text

## DN [Opcon] bash,recources
## text line
## another text line
## DN [Opcon] ends here

more text
```

With the user specifying either `Opcon`, `bash` or `recources`, the section gets printed in the terminal.

To get the output

```
## DN [Opcon] bash,recources
## text line
## another text line
## DN [Opcon] ends here
```

For the search pattern I have constructed the following, `ptn` being the pattern matching
`## DN [TITLE] KEYWORD,KEYWORD`.

```
  dpn='[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]DN[[:space:]]\[.*\]'
  kpn='[[:space:]][^,]+(,[^,]+)*'

  ptn="^($dpn)($kpn)?$"
```

Have done an initial try with `awk`

```
dn_ere='^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]DN[[:space:]]\[.*\]'

beg_ere="${dn_ere} ${keyword}$"
end_ere="${dn_ere} ends here$"

awk -v begpn="$beg_ere" -v endpn="$end_ere" \
  '$0 ~ begpn { insc=1; next }
   $0 ~ endpn { insc=0; print "" }
   insc { print }' "$efile"
```

The difficulty is to match the `keyword` in `beg_ere` because I would not know whether the match is in the first keyword, or the second, etc.

Comment: Veak, you're generating so many questions people don't have time to answer one before you ask the next. Please consider using a shell scripting tutorial and learn something about writing code

Comment: It is this question that remains.  Usually people suggest to split a question into many small questions, so I did that.

Comment: @Veak people suggest that indeed, when it's the alternative to a tremendously complex single post. Your posts can *all* be answered with: please post the first of your small questions, and try to learn from the answers (that should solve the others, at least partially) – or as roaima suggests: you seem to be very handy with regular expressions, which in all honesty is the harder thing about the scripts you need to write. Maybe be more specific about the code you're missing – right now it looks like you need to get a shell scripting tutorial as answer to multiple of your questions :)

Comment: Please try to understand that people are definitely not here to solve your finely packaged sequence of tasks. We're all here to help you understand! And I don't know whether "learning" goes well with asking 13 questions in but two days, a lot of which were already duplicates or underresearched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composing a regex pattern from two short ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733688/composing-a-regex-pattern-from-two-short-ones)

Comment: My actual problem in on how to use `awk` or `sed` to match the sections defined by the `DN` structure, but only when there is a `title` or `keyword` match.  For instance, I would ask to print all `DN` sections containing keyword `resource` or title `Opcon`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed - Print lines matched by a pattern range if one line matches a condition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228699/sed-print-lines-matched-by-a-pattern-range-if-one-line-matches-a-condition)