# sed - Print lines matched by a pattern range if one line matches a condition with ^

Tags: text-processing, sed

I found this question and it solved 99% of my issue but I can't figure out to match the end pattern with `^`.
[sed - Print lines matched by a pattern range if one line matches a condition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228699/sed-print-lines-matched-by-a-pattern-range-if-one-line-matches-a-condition)

Here are my data, it requires me matching the closing bracket at beginning of the line.

```
(
Device=B
Data=asdfasdf(qwfw)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(aewf)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
(
Device=B
Data=asdfasdf(wef)
)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(jalks)
)
(
Device=B
Data=asdfasdf(asf)
)
(
Device=C
Data=asdfasdf(asfew)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
```

I'm trying this command, but it fails to match anything.

```
sed -n '/(/{:a;N;/^)/!ba;/Device=A/p}' file
```

If I remove `^`, it returns this

```
-> % sed -n '/(/{:a;N;/)/!ba;/Device=A/p}'  test 
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(aewf)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(jalks)
```

Does anyone know what am I missing here?

sed version

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: sed is not a good tool for this.  Grep is the regex tool meant for pattern matching and Awk is the tool for pattern matching with complex logic.  For a multi-line match like this it is probably MUCH easier to do it using awk.

Answer (score 3):

When you are accumulating lines in the pattern space you can no longer use `^`  to match the beginning of subsequent lines and have to use `\n` (embedded newline) instead:

```
sed -n '/(/{:a;N;/\n)/!ba; /Device=A/p}' infile
```

although I very much prefer [Costas' solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228737) over there (working with the hold buffer is usually easier/better):

```
sed 'H;/^(/h;/^)/!d;x;/Device=A/!d' infile
```

In this case the `^` anchor is needed for both patterns.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to do this with sed you're using arcane constructs that became obsolete literally almost half a century ago when awk was invented. Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n)\n' '/Device=A/{ORS=RT; print}' file
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(aewf)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(jalks)
)
```

or using any awk:

```
$ awk '{r=r $0 ORS} /^)/{if (r ~ /Device=A/) printf "%s", r; r=""}' file
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(aewf)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(jalks)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6

```perl
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb( /^^ \( \n "Device=A" \n [\N+ \n]+? \) $$ / );'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb: /^^ \( \n "Device=A" \n [\N+ \n]+? \) $$ / ;'  file
```

Briefly, Raku has a function `comb` which is quite the opposite of `split`. You can give `comb` a Regex-matcher and it will pull out matching elements.

The code above `slurp`s the file in (reads-in all lines at once), without auto-chomping each line. To pull out `Device=A` elements, simply list the matching lines you desire (including `\n` newlines, which are still present).

Note: the grouping `[\N+ \n]+?` is a non-greedy sequence of one-or-more `\N` non-newline characters followed by a `\n` newline, this `[`...`]` grouped-pattern appearing `+` one-or more times, `?` non-greedily.

Sample Output:

```
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(aewf)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(jalks)
)
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed solution:

```
$ sed -n '/=A/,/^)/p' infile | sed '/=A/i ('

(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(aewf)
Lorem=Ipsum
)
(
Device=A
Data=asdfasdf(jalks)
)
```